# In Kafka streams joins, will second joining fields go to queue for waiting for the first fields to join in a window?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say we have two Kafka streams where A of stream 1 has to join with A of stream 2. And B of stream 1 has to join with B of stream 2. Something like this below:
A1 -> A2
B1 -> B2

Where '->' denotes the join and the corresponding number with the letter denotes the number of stream.

Now, let's look at the example below:

Stream 1   ---   Stream 2   ---   Join
                           
A
    B
                           
B           (B, B)

Now, my question is: will that **(B, B)** join happen or it'll first wait for the A of Stream 1 to arrive so that A1 -> A2 can happen first?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Confluent docs:

There are three joins in Kstreams: 
1. Inner Join
2. Left Join
3. Right Join

Sr.no. -> LeftStream1 -> RightStream -> Inner Join -> Left Join -> Outer Join

1. ->   null -> A -> null -> null -> null
2. ->   B    ->  null  -> [B, A] -> [B, A] -> [B, A]
3. -> null  ->  B  -> [B, A],[B, B]| -> [B, A],[B, B]  -> [B, A],[B, B]

The join between the [B,A] will happen first as the Right Stream already has an existing value and when a value enters in the Left Stream (as indicated in Sr. no. 2 ) It will carry out All the three joins.

Comment: That's right. Thanks. Although, my case is a little different. In my case, A has to join only with A and not B (let's say it's based on any joining condition like matching keys). Then, will the [B, B] happen or it'll first wait for [A, A] to happen even if both B1 and B2 have arrived already in their corresponding streams in a window? Does order matter here?